# Problems with ICMP socket socket2 crate

Tags: sockets, rust, udp, ping, icmp

I've written an application to send and receive ICMP packets (a ping redo, so to speak).

I've tested this on different computers and found that the code only runs on my MacOS. Other linux machines (I tested on many different flavors of Linux) gave wrong results, and I don't even know where to debug anymore.

Expected output, this is what comes out of my MacOS

```
[2022-06-17T18:37:47Z INFO  layer4_ip] Received 84 bytes from 142.250.69.206:0
[2022-06-17T18:37:47Z INFO  layer4_ip] Received Ipv4Packet { version : 4, header_length : 5, dscp : 0, ecn : 0, total_length : 16384, identification : 0, flags : 0, fragment_offset : 0, ttl : 119, next_level_protocol : IpNextHeaderProtocol(1), checksum : 44214, source : 142.250.69.206, destination : 192.168.1.130, options : [],  }
[2022-06-17T18:37:48Z INFO  layer4_ip] Received 84 bytes from 142.250.69.206:0
[2022-06-17T18:37:48Z INFO  layer4_ip] Received Ipv4Packet { version : 4, header_length : 5, dscp : 0, ecn : 0, total_length : 16384, identification : 0, flags : 0, fragment_offset : 0, ttl : 119, next_level_protocol : IpNextHeaderProtocol(1), checksum : 44214, source : 142.250.69.206, destination : 192.168.1.130, options : [],  }
```

Linux output (wrong output):

```
[2022-06-17T18:32:54Z INFO  ping_playground] Received 64 bytes from 142.250.69.206:0
[2022-06-17T18:32:54Z INFO  ping_playground] Received Ipv4Packet { version : 0, header_length : 0, dscp : 0, ecn : 0, total_length : 65454, identification : 80, flags : 0, fragment_offset : 1, ttl : 0, next_level_protocol : IpNextHeaderProtocol(0), checksum : 0, source : 0.0.0.0, destination : 0.0.0.0, options : [],  }
[2022-06-17T18:32:55Z INFO  ping_playground] Received 64 bytes from 142.250.69.206:0
[2022-06-17T18:32:55Z INFO  ping_playground] Received Ipv4Packet { version : 0, header_length : 0, dscp : 0, ecn : 0, total_length : 65454, identification : 80, flags : 0, fragment_offset : 1, ttl : 0, next_level_protocol : IpNextHeaderProtocol(0), checksum : 0, source : 0.0.0.0, destination : 0.0.0.0, options : [],  }
```

Not only the number of bytes read is different, but the parsing is wrong.
Intercepting in wireshark shows that the packets that are received back are indeed the same on my MacOS and Linux machines.

Here's the minimal version that presents the problem:

```rust
use std::{
    net::{IpAddr, Ipv4Addr, SocketAddr},
    os::unix::prelude::{AsRawFd, FromRawFd},
    sync::Arc,
    time::Duration,
};

use env_logger::Env;
use log::info;
use pnet_packet::{
    icmp::{self},
    Packet,
};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    env_logger::Builder::from_env(Env::default().default_filter_or("info")).init();

    // SOURCE IP ADDRESS
    // let localhost = Ipv4Addr::LOCALHOST;
    let localhost = Ipv4Addr::UNSPECIFIED;
    let socket_ip_address = SocketAddr::new(IpAddr::V4(localhost), 80);
    let socket2_ip_address = socket_ip_address.into();

    // CREATE ICMP SOCKET
    let socket2_ipv4_socket = socket2::Socket::new(
        socket2::Domain::IPV4,
        socket2::Type::DGRAM,
        Some(socket2::Protocol::ICMPV4),
    )
    .unwrap();

    // BIND TO LOCAL ADDRESS
    socket2_ipv4_socket
        .bind(&socket2_ip_address)
        .expect(&format!(
            "Failed binding to Ipv4 address {:?}",
            &socket_ip_address
        ));

    // CREATE STD SOCKET FROM SOCKET2 SOCKET
    let raw_ipv4_socket = socket2_ipv4_socket.as_raw_fd();
    let std_ipv4_socket = unsafe { std::net::UdpSocket::from_raw_fd(raw_ipv4_socket) };
    std_ipv4_socket.set_read_timeout(Some(Duration::from_millis(100)))?;
    let socket_arc = Arc::new(std_ipv4_socket);
    let dest = "142.250.69.206:0";

    let mut buffer = [0; 1024];
    let socket_clone = Arc::clone(&socket_arc);
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        let packet_slice = &mut [0; 56];
        let mut buf = vec![0; 8 + 56]; // 8 bytes of header, then payload
        let mut packet = icmp::echo_request::MutableEchoRequestPacket::new(&mut buf[..]).unwrap();
        packet.set_icmp_type(icmp::IcmpTypes::EchoRequest);
        packet.set_identifier(1);
        packet.set_sequence_number(1);
        packet.set_payload(packet_slice);

        // Calculate and set the checksum
        let icmp_packet = icmp::IcmpPacket::new(packet.packet()).unwrap();
        let checksum = icmp::checksum(&icmp_packet);
        packet.set_checksum(checksum);
        loop {
            socket_clone.send_to(&mut packet.packet(), dest).unwrap();
            std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
        }
    });

    loop {
        if let Ok((bytes_read, from)) = socket_arc.recv_from(&mut buffer) {
            info!("Received {} bytes from {:?}", bytes_read, from);
            let ipv4_packet = pnet_packet::ipv4::Ipv4Packet::new(&buffer).unwrap();
            let _icmp_packet = pnet_packet::icmp::IcmpPacket::new(ipv4_packet.payload()).unwrap();
            let _udp_packet = pnet_packet::udp::UdpPacket::new(&ipv4_packet.payload()).unwrap();
            info!("Received {:?}", ipv4_packet);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the dependencies part of Cargo.toml:

```ini
[dependencies]
pnet_packet = "0.29"
log = "0.4"
env_logger = "0.9"
socket2 = "0.4"
```

First, I would like someone to confirm this behavior.
Second, I would like help in figuring out what's wrong.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Dummy me.
To receive the IP header I had to use a RAW socket and not the DGRAM.
Changing the socket creation to:

```rust
let socket2_ipv4_socket = socket2::Socket::new(
        socket2::Domain::IPV4,
        socket2::Type::RAW,
        Some(socket2::Protocol::ICMPV4),
    )
    .unwrap();
```

That comes with the caveat that you have to give the right capabilities to your binary. Something like this, for example:

```bash
cargo build && sudo sudo setcap cap_net_raw+ep target/debug/ping_playground && target/debug/ping_playground
```

Closing the question.